# Why are the spans not centering within this div?

Tags: html, css

i have 2 spans within a span to center next to eachother, class inside_span up and inside_span down, they are aligned to the left of the pulse_result_format span, i have tried margin: 0 auto on the pulse result format span, does not work, and display: inline-block;

HTML:

```
<div class="pulse_votes_container thumb1">
    <span class="pulse_vote_buttons">
    </span>
    <span class="pulse_result_format">
        <span class='inside_span up'>{up}</span>
        <span class='inside_span down'>{down}</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inside_span {

    display: inline-block;
    width:40%;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    margin: 10% auto 0px 0px;
    float:left;
}

.down {

    background-color:#FF6E25;
}

.up {

    background-color: rgb(70, 136, 71);
}

.pulse_result_format {

    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;

    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.pulse_votes_container {

    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float:left` from `.inside_span`

```
.inside_span {
    display: inline-block;
    width:40%;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    margin: 10% auto 0px 0px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cM49u/)**